# how to link dropdown menu to other class

Tags: sql, vb.net, drop-down-menu

i have  a problem where i have to link dropdown menu to other class, which the class is sqlcommand

so my code a bit much like this

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Input
   Dim CallSQL As New SQL Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As 
             System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    If ListBox1.SelectedValue = "A" Then
      -------"I DONT KNOW HOW TO COMMAND HERE "--
    End If
    If ListBox1.SelectedValue = "B" Then
      -------"I DONT KNOW HOW TO COMMAND HERE "---------
      End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and i need to match the dropdown from here

SQL.vb

```
Public Class SQL 

Private Sub GetRoadDataFromDatabase(station)
    ExecuteSqlCommand("exec '" & station & "', 'A'", "TableA")
End Sub

Public Sub GettrainDataFromDatabase(station) 
    ExecuteSqlCommand("exec  '" & station & "', 'B'", "TableB")
End Sub
```

so when user choose A, executesql data for road, and when choose B execute data for train. please help me.this suppose to be a simple task. but since im new in vb.bet i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute `GetRoadDataFromDatabase` if user selects option 'A' and `GetTrainDataFromDatabase` if user selects `B`. Simply create instance of `SQL` class outside of `IF/ELSE` statements and call relevant method in `IF/ELSE`:

```
Public Class Input
   Dim CallSQL As New SQL Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As 
             System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.Visible = True
    Dim sql AS SQL =new SQL() 'Please check this if it is valid VB.Net statement
    If ListBox1.SelectedValue = "A" Then
        'Supposing you have got station already
        sql.GetRoadDataFromDatabase(station)
    End If
    If ListBox1.SelectedValue = "B" Then
        'Supposing you have got station already
        sql.GettrainDataFromDatabase(station)
    End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**EDIT:- Not making methods public**

As you have stated that you don't want to make the two functions public, an option is to write a gateway function to accept parameters and then call the desired private method.

```
Public Class SQL 

    Private Sub GetRoadDataFromDatabase(station)
        ExecuteSqlCommand("exec '" & station & "', 'A'", "TableA")
    End Sub

    'THOUGH YOUR THIS FUNCTION IS PUBLIC IN QUESTION
    Private Sub GettrainDataFromDatabase(station) 
        ExecuteSqlCommand("exec  '" & station & "', 'B'", "TableB")
    End Sub 

    Public Sub CallDBFunction(station as string, code as string)
        If code == "A" Then
            GetRoadDataFromDatabase(station)
        Else
            GetTrainDataFromDatabse(station)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: yes, that is the problem, because it has to be private. this is confusing me

Comment: @thevillageidiot i tried the same way already, but it stated that  "reference to a non-shared member requires an object references.

Comment: Yep sorry missed that @SimonMᶜKenzie you are right, the methods has to be public (or shared or friendly as they call in VB)

Comment: so does this comment means? "reference to a non-shared member requires an object references"

Comment: @zayya, it means that when you tried the code above, you didn't create an instance of `SQL` (i.e. `Dim sql AS New SQL`), so you were trying to call your method statically.

Comment: nope, you do need object to refer non-shared methods but that method either should be public or internal (don't know what is in vb.net).

Comment: so there is no other way if i dont want to change from private to public??

Comment: is there any option like i declare A and B into a string and connect it the sql class whenever person choose a or b?